# Phantom or blank pages between chapters

Tags: blank-page

I am setting a book for Springer using their style sheet and have hit a problem where I am getting phantom pages between chapters. The complete book comprises front matter, toc, list of tables, 36 chapters, 6 appendices and an index (around 700 pages). I have managed to duplicate the problem with two chapters. The first chapter (1-12) ends on an even page (12) and the next chapter should start on the next right odd hand page. Instead I get an odd blank page with a running head, (13) and then a totally blank even page (15). The next chapter then starts as I would expect on page 15. I have put the files up at

http://rhymneyconsulting.co.uk/fortran/third_edition/

chap02.tex and chap03.tex are the two chapters, third_edition.tex 
is the book tex file. I have put up a pdf showing the problem.
svmono.cls is the latex style sheet. our_acknowledgement.tex
is part of the front matter.

Are these files sufficient for someone to have a look and give me some pointers
as to where I might be going wrong?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Try to make a Minimal (Non-)Working Example (M(N)WE) narrowing the files down to the least code that raises the unexpected behaviour, since most of the code is non relevant for the question being asked.

Comment: I can't even replicate it by compiling the files you provided, but I guess your problem is the `sectrefs` option which should set a bibliography for each chapter. In your case it's empty, so you get an empty page.

Comment: I tried\documentclass[graybox,envcountchap]{svmono} and still get the problem. what version are you using? here is part of the header of the log file. This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) (preloaded format=latex 2013.11.30)  6 FEB 2015 10:42
entering extended mode
**third_edition.tex
(D:\document\fortran\third_edition\latex_source\third_edition.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27> I have the same problem when running on a SuSe distribution

Comment: I get an identical document as the example, just with the two empty pages missing. Strange.

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by the `\include` command, which always starts a new page. You then get a completely blank page so that the next chapter starts on an odd page.

If you use `\input` rather than `\include`, the problem will go away.

Comment: Have you tried it? Because I couldn't even reproduce it with the files provided. Also I always include my chapters with `include` without having the same problem.

Comment: @JuriRobl --- Yes. It fixes the problem in the example provided.

Comment: Then my distribution (current TeXLive) is strange, I don't get any empty pages with the code provided.

Comment: @JuriRobl --- I've tried TeXLive 2012 and TeXLive 2014. In both cases pages 23 and 24 are blank if `\include` is used. With `\input` the problem does not occur. Some classes/packages might be smart enough to deal with the new page created by `\include`, but it's better to use `\input` in most cases.

Comment: I replaced \include with \input and now only get the problem between appendices b and c for the whole book. Thanks for the help. I need to have a look at appendix b and c a bit more as appendix b is a multipage table, and I need to check that I've got everything correct. I 'may be back' as the phrase goes....

Comment: As Juri said that he could not duplicate the problem I feel that I should have said that in the full publication (36 chapters, 6 appendices) that the problem only showed up between chapters 2 and 3, 11 and 12 and appendix b and c when using \include rather than \input.