# Blank page generated when using `\subsection{Results}` inside landscape

Tags: landscape, sections-paragraphs, blank-page

I have a problem when using the landscape feature in LaTex. Specifically, if I include the `\subsection{Results}` inside the landscape a blank page is generated in landscape before the page of interest.

When I comment out the `\subsection{Results}` the blank page is not generated.

Below is my code:

```
\begin{landscape}

    \subsection{Results}

        \begin{figure}[H] 

            \begin{center}

             \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, width=8in]{Experiment_4.pdf}
             \captionof{figure}{\label{fig:Experiment 4}Experiment 4.}


            \end{center}

        \end{figure}

\end{landscape}
```

Any ideas on how to retain the `\subsection{Results}` and get rid of the blank page?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Full minimal example please.

Comment: @daleif what additional information should I provide? I'm unsure what your looking for. My document is enormous.

Comment: Se need something that is compilable on its own, otherwise we cannot help. You are also making so many wrong things here (for example, don't use the center env to center inside a float, use `\centering` instead of `\begin{center}` and remove `\end{center}`). You need to make the smallest possible fully compilable document that shows your problem

Comment: You might also take a look at the following questions to see if  they apply to your document.  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226837/phantom-or-blank-pages-between-chapters?rq=1 http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/252054/blank-page-removal?rq=1

Comment: @daleif thanks. James thank you for the links. I did check them out but discovered the solution in a different previous submission. Thanks for taking the time to have look though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was pretty straight forward in the end.

The reason adding the `\subsection{Results}` inside the landscape was causing the issue was because the image was large to begin with and the addition of the heading caused it to 'spill over' into two pages, hence the blank page.

I simply adjusted the code as follows:

```
\includegraphics[scale=.35, keepaspectratio]{Experiment_4.pdf}
```

This fitted the image and text to the page and ensured there was no 'spilling over' and thus no blank page was generated.